# convert LocalDatetime to timestamp

Tags: c#, datetime

I have an MVC application.

At controller(from view) I am getting start date as string "Tue Jan 01 2008 00:00:00 GMT 0100 (Central Europe Standard Time)".

Could anybody please tell me how to convert this datetime to normal dd-mmy-yyyy hh:mm:ss at Controller level.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: @Greg DateTime.Parse(startdate) thows error :  String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Comment: var date = DateTime.ParseExact(yourDate, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Comment: @User555 DateTime.ParseExact(yourDate, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); throws error : String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Comment: What is generating the date - Javascript?

Comment: why there is a down vote. I have serached enough on the internet and have tried also (all types of Parsing and culture Info)... @Downvoter : Please provide the answer or if u dont know the answer try to search on the internet and see how much effort have i already put.

Comment: @Greg: At view level , A framework named Telerik ahs been used to generate different grid views. I m not well versed with Telerik thats why trying to comvert date at controller level.

Comment: OK - the default model binder should handle that conversion automatically.

Comment: As a test , run this string into the controller and see if it works.... it seems your date format is different from what the model binder expects : This is how a properly formatted string should look : Wed Mar 25 2015 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (W. Europe Standard Time) - Notice the Difference here : GMT+0100

Comment: There is _no_ way to parse your string to DateTime without using `GMT 0100 (Central Europe Standard Time)` part as a string literal delimiter.

Comment: It sounds to me like you need to go back to your JavaScript code, (in Telerik, if that's what you're using) and send the dates to your controller in a sane format like ISO8601.  The string you're sending now will likely vary considerably across different browsers - especially with regard to the time zone portion.  You cannot expect consistency, or that the controller will always be able to parse the time zone.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) method and supply the correct format string so the code knows what each part of the input string represents.

```
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
string format = "ddd MMM dd yyyy hh:mm tt zzz";
result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, provider);
```

Double check the format strings [against the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) there are several subtle and not so subtle gotchas:

- "h" represents the hour in 12 hour clock
- "hh" represents the hour in 12 hour clock with leading zero
- "HH" represents the hour in 24 hour clock with leading zero
- "m" represents a minute from 0 to 59
- "M" represents a month from 1 to 12

etc.

So you may find that you think your format string is OK for the examples you have, but then a new string will come along which won't parse. You'll have to examine it to see if you've got hours in 12 or 24 hour format, etc.

Though you will have to strip of the timezone name from the end of the string first as that won't be recognised by `ParseExact`.

Comment: There is no [zzzz](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131038(v=vs.110).aspx) modificator and then this code throws an exception even without timezone name.

Comment: @VadimMartynov - oops. Typo. Plus I'd got `dd` and `MMM` the wrong way round.

Comment: @ChrisF : still thows an error: tring was not recognized as a valid DateTime. I have removed timezone from date string, then also it throws error.

Comment: @Rupesh, that's because you hour format is two digits not one. I *always* miss that.

Comment: No still does not work. I think it's becaue 0100 is not matching by "zzz" format which expect timezome with : and + sign.

Comment: @VadimMartynov in that case, I'm not sure what format string you need, perhaps you might have to remove the `:` prior to parsing?

Comment: @ChrisF Don't worry, there is no way to parse `0100` as a UTC Offset.